# How To Prevent Losing App Name on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have created a new App on iTunes Connection on April 24th but my application is still not finished. It appears I am still able to upload the app (assuming it is complete) as the App still shows in iTunes Connect with the status of "1.0 Prepare for Submission". I am right at the 180 day mark, so I'm sure I will lose my name tonight.

What can I do to prevent my name from being lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I heard back from iTunes Connect and here's what the nice guy there had to say about this question:

> I understand that you are concerned with loosing your app name.
>
> I have great news!  **App names no longer expire**, so you will not loose
>   your name!

I can verify that I still have my App name today... what a relief!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, other than providing a binary, you can't do anything else, from **iTunes Connect Developer Guide**: [Note:  Per section 3.2 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, squatting on an app name to prevent legitimate third-party use is prohibited.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW4)

Comment: I was able to upload the application as-is to iTunes Connect, and it is showing in the pre-release section with a status of "Invalid Binary". Is this enough to save my name?

Comment: To be honest, no idea. I guess you can buy a bit time with uploading invalid binaries and rejecting them, but I can't tell how much.